# How can I use a User Filtered Date to drive Calculations in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, sage50

I am trying to create an Aged Creditors report in Power BI, using data from Sage 50. I have extracted Account_Ref, Date and Gross_Amount from the Audit_Split table, to which I can then apply a user filter for Date, which will give me the correct Balance totals for each account.

My difficulty arises when I try to place any outstanding balance in the periods; Current, 30 days, 60 days etc, because in order to calculate which period to place a transaction, I need to know the last day of the reporting period (ie, the use filter date).

I believe that a custom field won't recalculate based on a user filter (assuming you can make use of the user date), but that a measure might be my solution.

Can Dax reference a user filter date at all?

Please help.

Comment: "I need to know the last day of the reporting period (ie, the use filter date)." 
This sounds like you don't have a Calendar table. Because a reporting period sounds like something you'd have in your Date dimension/Calendar table.

Comment: I don't have a Calendar table, just the data tables that Sage provides. I am hoping to allow the user to filter based on the Date field from the Audit_Split table, and to use the date they choose to calculate the Aged periods. If you can explain how a Calendar table would help achieve what I want, I'd be happy to add it by importing from a spreadsheet, if necessary.

Comment: you can create your own calendar table using DAX or using PowerQuery. Since I'm terrible at PowerQuery, I tend to use DAX. Goes something like this:
DimDate = CALENDAR(MINX('FactTable'[DateColumn]), MAXX('FactTable',[DateColumn]) )
you can use ADDCOLUMNS() with that to add whatever columns you like that you may want to slice by... year, month, reporting period...

Comment: I will look into this, but I'm still not clear how having this calendar table will help me to calculate my periods.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, sorry! If all you need to do is calculate the age of each transaction or invoice (for example), and you want to compare it to a selected date (say from a date slicer), then you need to do two things:

Create a measure to harvest the selected date value:

```
SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(DimDate[Date])
```

Create a calculated column in your "Invoices" table:

```
Age = INT([SelectedDate] - [Due Date])
```

Create a calculated column in your Transactions table that calculates the age of an item:

```
Age Bin = SWITCH(TRUE(),
        [Age]<30,"Less than 30",
        [Age]<60,"Between 30 and 59",
        [Age]<90,"Between 60 and 89",
        "90+")
```

Now that there's an "Age Bin", we can create a table of Invoices that count the number of invoices or sum the outstanding amounts by "age bin".

There. I think that may answer your question. Apologies for not understanding the first time.

Comment: Can you clarify how the SelectedDate is set please? When I've added a slicer, it has always had two dates (earliest and latest), so which of the two dates would this line use? Also, I'm not clear how the SELECTEDVALUE(DimDate[Date]) actually works, when there is no actual reference to the slicer object, I've tried this approach and the measure has never successfully picked up the end date.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you calculate the age of an item by doing something like this:
INT(TODAY() - [DueDate])
Then you can use the SWITCH() stuff in a calculated column to determine the "age" bin each invoice goes in.

Comment: Not a silly question, however, the business may want to look at the situation at the end of Qtr2, even though a few weeks may have passed. Sage 50 gives the user the option to exclude later transactions from the report date (ie 30th June for Qtr2) and I presume that the aged periods also run from the report date, not from the present day.

Comment: How are periods determined? Are they based on your calendar (like Q1, Q2...) You could use those to filter your dataset.
FILTER('FactTable',DimDate[Year]=SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[Year]) && 'DimDate'[Quarter]<=SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[Quarter]))

Comment: No, they are custom periods based on date of report, which may be quarter end, but may not be. I need them to be dynamic, or at least dependent on user input.

Comment: dynamic how? Like have the user choose the time period size (week, month, quarter, etc) and then choose a date range? For the varying time period size, I would use a parameter, and then the range, I'd just use a Between slicer on date.

Comment: Well, I keep butting up against the fact that calculated columns don't update based on user input (like a slicer), they only update with the rest of the query, even when the calculated columns are part of a append query of other source data queries.

Comment: And in answer to your question; dynamic, in the sense that they measure 30/60/90 days from the date of the report (chosen by the user), so having them as fixed quarters isn't flexible enough.

Comment: so use a parameter to choose 30/60/90 and another to choose the StartDate, and then use FILTER() to get the records that fall within the window?

Comment: This is all fine, except, as I previously mentioned, any calculated columns do not update until the table itself is refreshed, so setting the measure does not change the calculated columns.